# How to select a row that contains a number by range?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get some help from you. I have a query what looks like this:
`SELECT id FROM level WHERE minXp <= $xp AND maxXp >= $xp`. My goal is to get rid of one column (*maxXp*) and only use *minXp*. But I can not find a fuction in sql to write a query that only select one row.

**My table looks like this now:**

```
id int(4) primary UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT 
minXp int(9) unique UNSIGNED
maxXp int(9) unique UNSIGNED
```

**Values:**

```
1 000 100
2 101 500
3 501 3000
etc
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by saying "get rid of 1 column". Do you mean you dont want it to be showed in result ?

Comment: I mean not to store the range in the table just the minimum value and find what is the max row that contains the XP. Like id-1 xp-100, id-2 xp-500, id-3 xp-3000 and I have an input value (552) select the correct id (id-2 beacuse that is the last value that reached by the input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming these are *tiled* -- that is no gaps or overlaps -- you can use:

```
SELECT id
FROM level
WHERE minXp <= $xp
ORDER BY minXP DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

If the ids are increasing as the ranges increase, you can use:

```
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM level
WHERE minXp <= $xp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I understand what you're asking, and if I'm right you can try using `lead()` - does the following work for you?

```
select id
from level
where  $xp >minXp and $xp < Lead(minXp,1) over(order by id)
```

Comment: This gave me this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'over(order by id) LIMIT 0, 25' at line 3. I Used that this way (331 is a test input and xp is the new name for the minXp column): select id from res_levels where 331 > xp and 331 < Lead(xp,1) over(order by id)